# Is there a cleaner Python version of my code for Euler Practice

Tags: python

If we list all the natural numbers below 10 that are multiples of 3 or 5, we get 3, 5, 6 and 9. The sum of these multiples is 23.

Find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000. My Python code worked I would like to know could it be improved or shortened?

```
  x = []
     y = []
     z = []
n = int(input())
for i in range(1, n+1):
    if i%3 == 0:
        x.append(i)
        r = sum (x)
for j in range(1, n+1):
    if j%5 == 0:
        y.append(j)
        s = sum(y)
for m in range(1, n+1):
    if m%3 == 0 and m%5 == 0:
        z.append(m)
        t = sum(z)


print((r+s)-t)
```

Comment: If your code worked, you have access to the discussion page where other solutions are shown. Did you try that? If your code works, this is the wrong site to ask for "improved or shortened." Try the [Code Review site](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) but be sure to read and follow their guidelines.

Comment: @RoryDaulton is right... once you found the solution to a particular problem you can see others' in projecteuler site. One hint though for this easy one, the solution shouldn't be longer than 1line ~50characters ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is considered cleaner
but to address the previous comment here's your one line solution I think:

```
n = int(input())
print((sum(list(range(0, n, 3)))+sum(list(range(0, n, 5))))-sum(list(range(0, n, 15))))
```